# Angular4 - Nested route with params

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I got a routing for my user profiles in Angular4

```
/* Frame Default */
{
    path: '', component: FrameDefaultComponent,
    children: [
        {path: 'home', component: SiteHomeComponent},
        {path: 'home/:page', component: SiteHomeComponent},
        {
            path: 'user/:id', component: SiteUserProfileComponent,
            children: [
                {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
                {path: 'home', component: SiteUserProfileHomeComponent},
                {path: 'about', component: SiteUserProfileAboutComponent}
            ]
        },
        {
            path: 'user/settings', component: SiteUserSettingsComponent,
            children: [
                {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
                {path: 'home', component: SiteUserProfileHomeComponent},
                {path: 'about', component: SiteUserProfileAboutComponent}
            ]
        },
        {path: 'demo', component: SiteDemoComponent}
    ]
},
```

The problem is that when i navigate to user/settings he try to open user/:id ... any idea how i can fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the order of your routes like this

```
{
  path: '', component: FrameDefaultComponent,
  children: [
  {path: 'home', component: SiteHomeComponent},
  {path: 'home/:page', component: SiteHomeComponent},
  {
    path: 'user/settings', component: SiteUserSettingsComponent,
    children: [
      {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
      {path: 'home', component: SiteUserProfileHomeComponent},
      {path: 'about', component: SiteUserProfileAboutComponent}
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'user/:id', component: SiteUserProfileComponent,
    children: [
      {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
      {path: 'home', component: SiteUserProfileHomeComponent},
      {path: 'about', component: SiteUserProfileAboutComponent}
    ]
  },
  {path: 'demo', component: SiteDemoComponent}
]
},
```

Comment: Thanks this works. But is this really the correctly "Clean" way?

Comment: Angular router works in this way. It find first matches route, in first case it took 'settings' for :id.