# Can't navigate passing parameters in routerLink

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I'm facing a strange issue: using routerLink I can navigate everywhere but If I add another route param to the current route, it doesn't work.

This is my navigator.component. I use the following code to pass a URL to my app-card component.

```
<div class="installations-grid" *ngIf="installations != null">
  <div class="no-cards" *ngIf="installations.length == 0"><p i18n="no_installations| no installations string">Nessuna installazione per questo progetto</p></div>
  <div class="box-cards" *ngFor="let installation of installations">
  <app-card [title]="installation.name" [image-url]="installation.url" [content-text]="installation.id" [url]="'/dashboard/map/' + project.id + '/' + installation.id"></app-card>
</div>
```

And this is where I use that url in my app-card component:

```
<mat-card class="card-component" [routerLink]='model.url'>...</mat-card>
```

I would navigate to something like **/dashboard/map/1/2/**.
This route is associated with another component. These are my dashboard module routes:

```
[{
    path: 'map/:projectId/:installationId',
    component: MapNavigatorComponent,
    canActivate:[AuthGuardService],
    resolve: {
        maps: NavigatorResolver
    },
    data: {
        searchBar: {
            enabled: true,
            autocomplete: true,
            searchType: 'vin'
          },
          permission: {
            only: [''], // TODO: mettere il permesso vero
            redirectTo: 'login'
          }
    }
},
{
    path: 'map/:projectId',
    component: InstallationNavigatorComponent,
    canActivate:[AuthGuardService],
    resolve: {
        installations: NavigatorResolver
    },
    data: {
        searchBar: {
            enabled: true,
            autocomplete: true,
            searchType: 'vin'
          },
          permission: {
            only: [''], // TODO: mettere il permesso vero
            redirectTo: 'login'
          }
    }
},
{
    path: 'map',
    component: ProjectsNavigatorComponent,
    canActivate:[AuthGuardService],
    resolve: {
        projects: NavigatorResolver
    },
    data: {
        searchBar: {
            enabled: true,
            autocomplete: true,
            searchType: 'vin'
          },
          permission: {
            only: [''], // TODO: mettere il permesso vero
            redirectTo: 'login'
          }
    }
}];
```

Any other route (like **/login**) works regularly...
Some factors that I think could be responsible for this behavior:

1. *InstallationNavigatorComponent* and *MapNavigatorComponent* both extend another base component (NavigatorComponent);
2. The dashboard module is lazy-loaded;

Any clues?

**Note**: it reaches NavigatorResolver, but the URL in the address bar and the shown component template remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

Build the array of path params and pass it to routerLink directive.
For example:
`modelUrl: Array<string> = ['dashboard', 'map', 'projectId', 'installationId']`

and assign it to routerLink
`<mat-card class="card-component" [routerLink]="modelUrl">...</mat-card>`
 where modelUrl is array of path params.

Note: I was facing the similar problem with the lazyloaded module and it worked when i passed an array to routerLink directive.

Comment: nope, even passing an array of params the problem remains... :(

Answer (score 0):

When you are using a RouterLink directive as an input (with square brackets, [routerLink]="arg"), it is expecting an array of strings as an argument.

```
<mat-card class="card-component" [routerLink]="['dashboard', 'map', project.id, installation.id]">...</mat-card>
```

If your case, you should use it like this:

```
<mat-card class="card-component" routerLink="{{ model.url }}">...<mat-card>
```

where *model.url* is:

```
model.url = '/dashboard/map/' + project.id + '/' + installation.id;
```

Comment: Try reordering your routes in your dashboard routing module.
The first on should be 'map', then 'map/:projectId' and in the end 'map/:projectId/:installationId'

[{
  path: 'map',
  ...
}, {
  path: 'map/:projectId',
  ...
}, {
  path: 'map/:projectId/:installationId',
  ...
}]

Comment: already tried.. The strange thing is that passing from 'map' to 'map/:projectId' works; it doesn't navigate only when passing from  _'map/:projectId'_ to _'map/:projectId/:installationId'_ or from _'map/:projectId/:installationId'_ to _'map/:projectId/:installationId/:mapId'_

Comment: Try using children routes instead:

[{ 'map', children: [ path: ':projectId', children: [{ path: ''}, { path: ':installationId' }]]]

Comment: Order of the routes is important. I think that you will solve that issue with children routes. You can read more about nested routing here https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/nested-routes/

Comment: Your problem is probably the same as this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842934/angular4-nested-route-with-params

Comment: Also, you should add { ..., pathMatch: 'full'} to your route objects

Answer (score 0):

Solved! There was a bug in my *NavigatorResolver* class.

Here I was calling this function:

```
getInstallations(projectID: string, ignoreCache = false): Observable<any> {
    if (!ignoreCache && this.cache[projectID] != null) {
        this.logger.debug("cache hit", this.cache[projectID]);

        return Observable.create(observer => {
            observer.next(this.cache[projectID]);
            observer.complete();
        });
    }
    else {
        let apiURL = `${Services.GET_INSTALLATIONS}/?project__id=${projectID}`;
        return this.apiService.get(apiURL).pipe(map(json => {
            let installations = json['objects'];
            this.cache[projectID] = installations;
            return installations;
        }));
    }
}
```

What I was missing is **observer.complete();**

Another alternative is to use:

```
return of(this.cache[projectID]);
```

in place of:

```
return Observable.create(observer => {
    observer.next(this.cache[projectID]);
    observer.complete();
});
```